# Not echoing a mysql query result

Tags: php, mysql

Not echoing result, I think because result is a sum and not a specific entry in the db?

```
<?PHP
error_reporting('E_ALL');
include('session.php');
include('config.php');
$sql="SELECT SUM(grading) FROM (SELECT * FROM 'trails' WHERE `name` = 'Free Flow' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5) AS DATA";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['grading'];
}
?>
```

Updated version giving lank page...

```
<?PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('session.php');
include('config.php');
$sql="SELECT SUM(grading) AS grading FROM (SELECT * FROM `trails` WHERE `name` = "Free Flow" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5) AS DATA";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['grading'];
}
?>
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(grading) as grading` before using in the row index.

Comment: Are you sure there's no error being reported here?  Check your PHP logs.

Comment: Apart from the right solution written from @AbhikChakraborty - ``error_reporting(E_ALL);`` instead of ``error_reporting('E_ALL');``. ``E_ALL`` is a constant.

Comment: Abhik, please elaborate? David no error is being thrown.. Query gives correct result in phpmyadmin.

Comment: And you shouldn't use mysql_* functions because they are deprecated. Visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for more information

Comment: Thanks so much guys been struggling with this for hours.. much appreciated, all of you.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an index to SUM, so:

```
SELECT SUM(grading) AS sum_grading FROM (SELECT * FROM trails WHERE `name` = 'Free Flow' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5) AS DATA
```

And then:

```
echo $row['sum_grading']
```

Answer (score 1):

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.
>
> Database, table, and column names cannot end with space characters.
>
> Database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not permitted in file names.
>
> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):

Remove apostrophes after FROM (i mean `FROM 'trails'`) and replace with backticks " ` ".

Your sql query would then look like this:

```
$sql="SELECT SUM(`grading`) as `grading`
      FROM (SELECT * FROM `trails` WHERE `name` = 'Free Flow'
      ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5) AS DATA";
```

---

Source: [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you connection is successfully connected, SQL query is correct, database table has entries and you are using correct column name to print like $row['grading'].

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from :

```
error_reporting('E_ALL');
```

'E_ALL' isn't the constant, it's a string. PHP will silently cast it to int, and make it the configuration value for error reporting.

```
 (int) 'E_ALL' == 0
```

error_reporting(0) hide all errors, that's why you got a blank page.